# How can we be Certain that Dark Matter Exists if we Cannot See it or Directly Detect It?

Tags: astrophysics, dark-matter, dark-energy

It seems very certain that dark matter exists and that it makes up **26.8% of the Universe today** (along with 68.3% Dark Energy and 4.9% Atoms), but how can this be if we **cannot see** it or directly **detect** it?

Comment: Have you read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter) ?  There is a long section on the observational evidence.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there evidence of dark matter in our galaxy?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25664/)

Comment: I feel like this should be a duplicate of *something*, but not the linked question. In fact, almost none of the evidence we have for dark matter comes from our own galaxy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows insufficient prior research (see the Wikipedia article). If the information of that article is included, it is too broad, because there is a lot of observational evidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the astrophysical observations which shows for example: much more bending expected in lights directions due to the gravity of the stars and galaxies we know. it means we know there are four example 2 galaxies which can bend the light which come from a third and farther galaxy. and the bending to the light due to these 2 galaxies should be X. but the observed bending is much more than X. so there should be something else which cause it to bend more.
It is one of the evidences... you can read more in Wiki or others.